# Generating excel sheet from MySql database using PHP

Tags: php, excel

I'm new to PHP. I'm using the following code to generate an excel sheet from Mysql database using PHP.

```
<?php
    include("../Connection/Connection.php");
    $db_con=new Connection();
    $db_con->get_connection();  //Opens a database connection. This function is contained in the  Connection.php which is included above.

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM country");
    if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
    $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
    $headers = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
    {
        $headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i);
    }

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    if ($fp && $result)
    {
            header('Content-Type: text/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
            header('Pragma: no-cache');
            header('Expires: 0');
            fputcsv($fp, $headers);

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
            {
                 fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
            }
            die;
     }
?>
```

The above code is working and it generates the specified file `export.csv` but the problem is that it generates each column from MySql in this file twice. In other words, each column is duplicated twice (headers displayed are not duplicated though). What is wrong with this code? What changes should be made so that it displays each column exactly once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mysql_fetch_row` instead.

`mysql_fetch_array` fetches an array with BOTH string indexes and numeric indexes, so each value is fetched twice. Your code would work with either `mysql_fetch_assoc` or `mysql_fetch_row`.

Comment: I did as you say and it worked as expected. Thanks for your time.